# Where to give unique name to element in Xcode / Visual Studio for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I am just getting started to build my first app for the iPhone with some experience building firmware for microcontrollers in C and Arduino code. I am following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/5jtiARNkEeE but became stuck at 16:12, the part where you need to give an unique name to some elements.

Since this tutorial Visual Studio let's you edit the Main Storyboard in Xcode, and I can't find the right field where to assign a unique name to each element. Can someone tell me where to enter this unique name. Or if there is some workaround so that all of my project can be edited from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Designer was deprecated in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.8, and removed in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.9.

The recommended way to build iOS user interfaces is directly on a Mac running Xcode.

For more information You can check this walkthrough
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/storyboards/